# 'If' statement in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, categories

I have post model with row named 'category' which stores strings with categories. I would like to change my routes that if I'm into `"blog"` category then it would display address like this: `mysite.com/blog/1` or if my post category would be `"portfolio"` it would display my post address like `mysite.com/portfolio/2` etc. Is it possible without making another table and storing there categories? I'm thinking about some route `if` statement, but at the moment can't figure out anything with it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this!

```
CATEGORIES = %w[portfolio blog sites]
      CATEGORIES.each do |cat|
    get cat + '/:id', controller: 'post', action: 'show'
  end
```

Or with a scope:

```
   CATEGORIES = %w[portfolio blog sites]
      CATEGORIES.each do |cat|
         scope cat do
    get '/:id', controller: 'post', action: 'show'
     end
   end
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would change my `post#view` route?

Comment: You have to change the action into 'view'. You could also use SOMEMODEL.all.each() to loop through a table.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just catch them all with

```
match ':category/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

Then you could filter by the `:category` value in the `params` hash in the controller.

```
@post = Post.where category: params[:category], id: params[:id]
```

Comment: I'm getting now an `undefined method 'title' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation` error when trying to enter `show` view of a single post. (title is one from post fields)

Comment: btw. I don't have `index` view already - I need now only `show` view but don't know how to define links in routes to stay with current category (they're changing from `mysite.com/portfolio/` to `mysite.com/posts/1` :/

Comment: That's probably related yo something elsewhere in your code. Try to trace the error to its source I'd say. The error message probably shows the troublesome line.

Comment: ok I'll take a look - in the meantime I was trying now do something like this: `match '/:category/:id' => 'posts#show', :requirements => {:category => "PORTFOLIO"}` but it doesn't work - maybe You have any idea how to solve it in my way?

Comment: That is kinda pointless, effectively same as `match '/portfolio/:id' => 'posts#show'`

Comment: okay, but how then define `link_to` to redirect me to `/portfolio/` and not to `/posts/` ?

Comment: Check the documentation on **named routes**, that should fix your problem